# Message "localhost is not responding" in IE in angular app

Tags: angular

I have made my application in Angular and i am facing issue regarding IE and Edge. My app is build to have list of components and all of them are working correctly in Chrome and Firefox, in IE almost all of them works correctly, only when i click one component my IE/Edge is crushing, message: "localhost is not responding".
I have tried solution with pollyfills and changes in tsconfig.json file (es5). Nothing works.
Does anyone have faced similiar issue?

Comment: Just to make sure: You did add the browsers to your browserlist file?

Comment: yes, i did add IE to browserlist